# How to fix Interrupted imbalance of nic multi-queue error in centos

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt

I have a qemu guest that runs centos7.5 .
I enable NIC multi-queue,and bound cpu.

```sh
# for line in `cat /proc/interrupts | grep input | grep virtio | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F[:] '{print $1}'` ; do ret=`cat /proc/irq/$line/smp_affinity`; echo $line $ret; done
27 0001
29 0002
31 0004
33 0008
35 0010
37 0020
39 0040
41 0080
```

When the virtual machine sends a large number of data packets for testing, it can be found that the interrupt allocation is unbalanced from the interrupt record.

```sh
 27:     745176          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio0-input.0
 29:          7     108734          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio0-input.1
 31:          1          0        235          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio0-input.2
 33:          1          0          0        121          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio0-input.3
 35:          1          0          0          0     760961          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio0-input.4
 37:          1          0          0          0          0        689          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio0-input.5
 39:          1          0          0          0          0          0     710062          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio0-input.6
 41:          1          0          0          0          0          0          0        118          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      virtio0-input.7
```

Only a few cpu have a relatively high amount of interrupt processing.
Why is this problem, how do I fix it?
please help me.